# CSOM SharePoint Search API filter files only

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, search, csom, search-results

Using CSOM Search API is there a way to filter for only files? Something similar to the following ListItem filter would be ideal:

```
ListItem.FileSystemObjectType.Equals(FileSystemObjectType.File)
```

Ex use case:

```
if (item.FileSystemObjectType.Equals(FileSystemObjectType.File))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

The only thing similar I have found in documentation would be using the filetype Keyword Query Language (KQL) filter:

```
filetype:docx
```

I'd like to avoid using that, however, as setting all the possible valid file types feels like a sloppy solution IMO. Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IsDocument` managed property to filter out the list items. The search Get API should look like this

```
http://server/_api/search/query?querytext='QueryText+And+IsDocument:true'
```

apart from `IsDocument` managed property you can also use

1. `contentclass:STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary` - if you want to search within document libraries only
2. `contenttype:CONTENT_TYPE_NAME` - if you want to search documents for particular content type.

Comment: Thanks, IsDocument should work perfectly for my use case and a clean solution. Just to note for other users I am using CSOM so would be 'IsDocument:1' in this case.